# Raspberry Pi VPN with 3g dongle for internet access

Tags: linux, networking, vpn, raspberry-pi, 3g

I'm trying to set up a VPN connection on my RPi, but always times out. I have a DDNS setup and the public IP address is updated using ddclient. I have a network machine connected to eth0 and a 3g dongle (eth1) connected via a powered usb hub, and have tested the settings with a normal router with port forwarding and all worked.

Unfortunately I need to put the Pi in a location where normal Internet connections are not available (hence the 3g dongle). The Pi seems to ignore or is unaware of any incoming connections when I try to connect with my pc. It may just be an *iptables* command that I have not yet worked out or some kind of routing issue. Can anyone help?

Comment: Unfortunatly due to 3g network providers using NAT, you public address is shared by other 3g users on the same network. Your wan ip address you are seeing is a internal address from your provider if i am correct?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe iptables might be blocking 3G key incomming traffic. You set up the wired schema but not the 3G one. If it doesn't answer in 3G, it has something to do with your permission/iptables.
Maybe check /etc/host.allow also.